# how to read Binary rdf use Jena thrift

Tags: java, binary, rdf, jena

I want to read RDF binary using jena thrift

this is my code

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("./rdfBinaryExample.trdf");
BufferedOutputStream bos2=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
ObjectOutputStream out2=new ObjectOutputStream(bos2);
RDFDataMgr.write(out2,m,RDFFormat.RDF_THRIFT);

byte[] test=bos.toByteArray();      
DatasetGraph ret = DatasetGraphFactory.create();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(test);
RDFDataMgr.read(ret, is, Lang.RDFTHRIFT);
is.close();
```

Comment: 1. The two part of code have different purpose (First part is not about reading as queried). 2. How is `bos` declared?

Comment: Do not use `ObjectOutputStream`.